# Can anybody please let me know what I am missing?

Tags: align, matrices

[image: I want it to look like this image]I have type the following code.

```
\begin{align*}
\RR = \left\{ a_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 0 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 0 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 1 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 0 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix}  \\
              a_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 1 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_6 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 1 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_7 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 1 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_8 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 0 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix}       
  \right\}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Missing for what?

Comment: What's the meaning of the command `\RR`?

Comment: `\left\{ ... \right\}` doesn't work across line breaks.

Comment: No not the command, \RR. I have \RR for \mathcal{R}. But I want to make

Comment: This giving me an error I want to type as in the picture. But its not compiling  and giving me an error. I saw \left\{ ... \right\} doesn't work across line breaks. How would I typeset like the image in align mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `\left ... \right` doesn't work across line breaks, you can use `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}` instead. Judging by the image I would also suggest `multline*` instead of `align*`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
R = \biggl\{ a_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 0 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 0 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 1 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 0 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix},  \\
              a_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 1 \\
                     0 & 0
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_6 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     0 & 1 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_7 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 1 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix},
              a_8 = \begin{pmatrix}
                     1 & 0 \\
                     0 & 1
                    \end{pmatrix}       
  \biggr\}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ManojKumar No problem. Remember that to mark questions as solved you can accept the answer you liked best, by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. (This goes for [all your previous questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43368/manoj-kumar?tab=questions) as well.)  You can also upvote any useful answer by clicking the upward pointing arrow next to the score.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Your (near all) comment should be an authomatic message for never-accepting-answers-users. :-) +1